# why margin does not work with component even defined with relative position

Tags: html, css

My code is as shown below:

xyz.html

```
<div class='main-container'>
    <div class="q-background">
    </div>
    <div class="q-text">
        <div>Order History</div>
    </div>

    <div class ="q-orders">
    </div>
</div>
```

xyz.scss

```
.main-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-top: -4rem;
    .q-background {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        height: 14.3vw;
        background: url("../../image/i-header-list.jpg") no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
    }
    .q-text {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 1rem;
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .q-orders {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 2rem;
        float: left;
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #ff3;
    }
}
```

now what happens here is **margin-top:1rem** does not work for **q-text** even after defining position:relative. So is there anything missing?

Comment: Suggestion: Put the compiled code in a snippet

Comment: If you go into DevTools and select your `.q-text` element, you'll see that it has a top margin of `16px`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmjapL - what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: With position set to relative, `top: 1rem` will move the element 1rem down from where it would have been positioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margin-top` is working on `.q-text`, but you set on the parent a `margin-top:-4rem`. You should avoid a negative value  on `margin`.

```css
.main-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.main-container .q-background {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14.3vw;
  background: url("../../image/i-header-list.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.main-container .q-text {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  top:0;
}
.main-container  .q-orders {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ff3;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-container'>
    <div class="q-background">
    </div>
    <div class="q-text">
        <div>Order History</div>
    </div>

    <div class ="q-orders">
    </div>
</div>
```